# Need gameover activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I'm new to android, and I'm trying my best to create a game. I'm trying to create a gameover screen for my game, and I though the best way to do that was to create an activity for a gameover screen. However, I'm not sure how to go about doing this.The problem seems to be that I cannot create an intent anywhere other than the activity class. So I can't see when the game should end, and then create a new activity without it being in the activity class. So I'm having trouble connecting my game model to my activity class, so that when the player dies, it would trigger a gameover activity. Where in my activity class should I put this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would place code such as (assuming your activity is `GameOverScreen extends Activity`):

```
Intent gameOverScreen = new Intent(this, GameOverScreen.class);
startActivity(gameOverScreen);
```

To do so from outside the activity (since `startActivity()` is a public method of the Activity class), you'd just do like this, using the instance of your game activity that I call `gameScreen` in this example:

```
Intent gameOverScreen = new Intent(gameScreen, GameOverScreen.class);
gameScreen.startActivity(gameOverScreen);
```

You should probably have a reference to the instance of your game activity stored to the model as a `Context` object at least for resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
  </activity>
             <activity android:name=".gameoveractivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="name-of-activity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Add this in your Manifest.xml...

Then from the code invoke this activity like this

```
  Intent i = new Intent("name-of-activity-you-declared-in-the-manifest");
          this.startActivity(i);
```

I guess you should put this after reaching conditions for game over. Let's say after loosing 3 lives, you get game over activity.

If you are doing game over with something like TRY AGAIN. Then you should use this.startActivityForResult(i, result). And then, override the onActivityResult() method in the class from where you call the game over activity.

Comment: But where do I call that though? That would have to be in the gameModel, and I cannot make intents in the game model, only in the game activity.

Comment: How are you structuring your game? The game should, in some way or another, be inside an activity: not a model.

Comment: Call it from the current activity. Or switch to activity where you think game over should be called and call it.

Comment: I have a class called gameCall which has an MVC framework. GameCall is the gameactivity. The model the view, the gamecontroller, and the gameloop, are all done in the gameCall.

Comment: Paste the code where you have stated conditions for game over. :)

Comment: <code> public void gameOver(long t){
  if(levelLose){
   
   entities.clear();
   entityDraw.clear();
   background=new Backgrounds(2,context.getResources());
   
   updateLevel();
  
   
   
  }else{
   entities.clear();
   entityDraw.clear();
   background=new Backgrounds(3,context.getResources());
   updateLevel();
  }
  
 } </code>

Comment: `public void gameOver(long t){
  if(levelLose){
   
   entities.clear();
   entityDraw.clear();
   background=new Backgrounds(2,context.getResources());
   
   updateLevel();
  
   
   
  }else{
   entities.clear();
   entityDraw.clear();
   background=new Backgrounds(3,context.getResources());
   updateLevel();
  }
  
 }`